# Access cannot filter on Unicode characters after tables migrated to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have moved MS Access 2010 Data to SQL using their tools, and now filtering by Unicode is not working in Access linked tables. I see the linked table column in SQL is "nvarchar" but in Access there is "Unicode compression" set to "No" and I can't change it.

Answer (score 5):

It is my understanding that the "Unicode compression" setting only affects native Access (ACE/Jet) tables and has no effect on ODBC linked tables. Instead, what you likely need to do is change the "Collation" setting of the SQL Server database itself by using SQL Server Management Studio:

[image: DatabaseProperties.png]

For example, with the above SQL Server collation setting ("SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS") I cannot filter on Greek characters (e.g., 'γιορτή') from Access, but if I change the collation of the SQL Server database to "Greek_CI_AS" then that same Access filter will work.

**Edit re: comments**

While this solution will work for single-byte code pages that are natively supported by SQL Server (e.g., Greek, which would correspond to Windows-1253), it won't work for languages that lack those code pages and must be represented either by

1. a code page that is not supported by SQL Server, or
2. Unicode.

ODBC linked tables in Access apparently do not fully support Unicode, passing search strings to SQL Server as `'text'`, not as `N'text'`, so SQL Server feels compelled to interpret any such text according to the selected single-byte code page (via the "Collation") setting.

Comment: For Armenian there is no special collation. In SQL search works fine =N'sometext'. but when I use search from MS Access in linked table there is no way to use =N'....', it converts to ='...' and not show the result. @Gord

Comment: @Gord, It doesn't solve the Microsoft access issue with linked ODBC. Microsoft Access displays and add the unicode text properly, but does not apply filter for a record which contains unicode characters.

Comment: @Madnik7G As I said in my answer, it worked for me when I tried it with Greek characters. What language are you trying to use? As noted in the earlier comment from arman, some languages like Armenian don't have native SQL Server support for collation. SQL Server can store and retrieve the Unicode characters, but sorting and searching can be problematic if the collation sequence doesn't quite match.

Comment: @Gord, I tried Persian language with texts containing its only unicode character YE "ی". It look the problem is caused by ODBC driver or access not SQL server. Data stored and retrieved successfully, but if you just execute a simple query (not pass-through query) or filter a column that have that Unicode character then you don't get any result. Even if you press right click on a Microsoft Access column and select EQUAL menu, you will see there is no result if that column contains "ی".

Comment: @Madnik7G Fair enough. I have seen similar comments elsewhere regarding ODBC linked tables . I have updated my answer to try and better explain why this is happening in your case.

Comment: Since you posted this in 2014 is there now a better solution?  I'm dealing with Japanese characters and the app I migrated to SQL Server has stopped working.

Comment: I was able to get my Access database with Japanese characters migrated to SQL Server by setting the SQL Server collation to `Japanese_90_CI_AI_KS_SC` ***before*** I ran the scripts to create the tables.  That was the only change I had to make.  No changes were needed to my queries, the ODBC driver, or Access settings.  I now have the same Access front-end working with a Japanese collation and the standard English collation with not struggles.  It took me a while to realize this was the only thing I needed, and I had even asked a few database experts who had no experience with collation.